# Disappear alpha, concentrations

Tags: acid-base

I have a doubt that torments me constantly ... And I hope your answer so that you can solve it. When they give me $K_{a}$ or $K_{b}$, the concentrations and they ask me to find alpha, when can I discard alpha?

Example:

$K_{b} = 1.79·10^{-5}$, $(NH_{3}) = 0.74M$, $\alpha =$

Okay, with these data I arrive at the following expression:

$K_{b} = (0.74·\alpha ^ 2) / (1-\alpha)$, here, in the "$1-\alpha$", can I discard?

I think the answer is no, but could you tell me why not? And in what cases can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "despise" you actually mean discard the value of alpha. As in making the approximation: $$(1-\alpha ) \approx 1$$
To answer your question we need to consider the meaning of alpha and the value of the equilibrium constant.

$\alpha$ represents the degree of ionization, i.e., the amount that dissociates from 1. If you say that $\alpha$ is 0.1, for example, then what you are saying is that for every 1M of concentration 0.1M dissociates. If you have a different concentration than 1M, then the amount that dissociates is $\alpha M$ where M is the concentration of your starting substance.

The equilibrium constant, K, tells you something about the relation between products and reactants. If K is greater than 1 then products are favored and if K is less than one reactants are favored (or, the reaction does not "like" to go towards the right).

Look at the value of your constant $K_b = 1.79 . 10^{-5}$. It is small. That should tell you that very little amount of your starting reactant will dissociate to yield products. Thus, we would expect the value of $\alpha$ to be small when compared to one. If this is the case then we can say that $$(1-\alpha ) \approx 1$$
If you solve the equation with the approximation you find $\alpha = 0.004906$ . If you solve the equation without approximation you get $\alpha = 0.004918$
Thus, it seems that the approximation is justified particularly if you don't need great precision in your answer.

So, when do you approximate? There is no a set answer to this. But, if your equilibrium constant is small ($ < 10^{-4}$) usually) and the concentration of your initial substance is big enough you can try and see what happens. The rule of thumb that I was told was to accept the approximation if the final result is less than 5% of the value of the approximated value. In this case, we obtained 0.004918 over a value of 1. This represents 0.5% and the approximation is justified.

Make sure you ask your professor what is the criterion he or she uses to justify an approximation.

Comment: Re; "So, when do you approximate? There is no a set answer to this. ..." // That really isn't correct. There is the concept of *significant figures*. The ammonia was noted as 0.74 molar. So the ammonia concentration is only good to +/- 0.005 molar.  That is 0.68%. This is about the same as assuming that $1 - \alpha \approx 1$, so the assumption is ok. This sort of assumption is used all the time in chemistry to simply the mathematical analysis. // This is different than in a math class where 0.74 means 0.740000000...

Comment: @MaxW You are technically correct.However, I have yet to find any instructor in General Chemistry that goes through that analysis of significant figures. The usual criterion, at least what I have heard most often, is the 5% criterion, that is, if your approximation is 5% or less of the value on which the approximation ws made it is taken as ok.

Comment: I was taught significant figures when I was in high school.